Digital IDP in Egypt
I want to rent a car from SIXT at Hurghada airport. In their booking process it says nothing about International Driver's Permits, but apparently Egypt required IDP in theory at least. Since there are lots of police or military checkpoints and Egyptians love baksheesh I'd like to avoid giving any excuses.
Is it allowed to use the digital IDP in Egypt, the one you can get in 8 minutes?
Does sixt or other car rentals require IDP at all and does it have to be physical?
I am already in Egypt and physical IDP is not an option. My license is EU.

What's a "digital idp"? Sounds like a scam

@littleadv I thought it might be legit, since the whole IDP thing is nonsense paperwork anyway, so why wouldn't it be legit if its done via online KYC type procedure?

Because rules and regulations and government authorities? Anyone can create a "digital" anything, who's to say it's valid? Not to say that the IDPs are hard to forge, but at least you need two different types of paper and a rubber stamp.

@littleadv my guess is that IDP is not 100% as clear, its essentially a translation of a drivers license, but most already are in english in addition to the local language. Is there really a need for legalized translation from english to english and couldn't a proper legalized non IDP translation also work?

IDP is not an english to english translation. Among other languages, IDP includes Arabic (which is what is spoken in Egypt) and several other non-latin script languages. It also uses common driving categories, whereas national driving licenses may use different categories.

It took me three comments to realise that "IDP" is not "Internally Displaced People", but "International Driver's Permit".

AFAIK, it is not just translation, but also better description on what you are allowed to do: every country has different categories, and it is not always simple to know. Older people may have a very generic license which allow nearly everything, later there were distinction to heavy vehicles, then with 2-wheels, etc. etc. (and sometime they got also the distinction "only automatic gear"). So the usefulness of IDP. Note: now we are standardizing more, so less countries or car rentals requires it (or not for all foreign countries). But bureaucracy is slow (if few economic interest pushed chg).

@littleadv That is a very strange arguments. Many documents related to driving are going digital now, at least in the EU. Yes, anyone can create anything. But some of them may be actually recognized by the authorities. Sometimes even internationally. This concerns, for example, the green cards https://www.cobx.org/article/10969/green-cards-accepted-electronic-format-start-2025

FYI: Are unofficial International Driving Permits of any use?; How can I check if an international driving permit is legit?

@VladimirFГероямслава you're presenting an even stranger argument. What does it matter that some other document in some other place is digitalized? The question is specifically about IDPs.

Here is the theory...
To be able to drive (and rent a car) in a country, you need to have a driver's license which is recognised by that country.
If you are resident of the country, there is usually a time limit for licenses from other countries to be recognised, after which only local licenses are accepted.
For visitors, what is acceptable depends on what international Convention on Road Traffic the visited country is party to.

If they are signatories to the older 1949 Geneva Convention, then:

They can (but are not required to) accept driver's licenses from other countries using the older 3-part pink format, using vehicle categories A to E
They can also require an International Driving permit using the 1949 format (grey cover, white pages, between 6 and 12 languages). They are most likely to do so if the national driver's license is in a language which is not recognised .


If they are signatories to the newer 1968 Vienna Convention (amended), then:

They should accept a driver's license from another country if it is in an official language of the visited country, or if accompanied by a certified translation
They should also accept licenses conforming to the 1968 standard (old three-part pink format and a few variations thereof using categories A to E for licenses issued up to 29 March 2011, new credit-card sized format with numbered fields and more categories after that).
And they should accept 1968-format IDPs (there are a number of changes in the format, including which languages must/can be included).



In all cases, conditions apply, like minimum age (18 in general, older for some categories), learners permits not being accepted, etc.
Wikipedia is not up to date, Egypt is party to the 1968 convention (since 15 Dec 2023). So if you have either an older 3-part pink drivers license issued before 29 March 2011, or the newer credit-card-sized EU drivers license, that should be enough. But since this is a relatively recent development, expect to encounter people who still think you need an IDP.
When an IDP is required, only IDPs issued by the official organization(s) for each country are valid. The official list (maintained by FIA/AIT) is here. Depending on the country, it is usually either the same authority which delivers national driver's licenses, or local AA chapters.
Do not order an IDP from anyone else. In particular, the official site lists a few scam sites on this page.
I'm not aware of "digital IDPs" having any validity anywhere. If they are issued by any of the sites listed on the page above, just forget about them.
Now in practice... Ask and they will tell you.

I asked sixt and they looked at me like im an alien and ignored me. Later I passed easily 20 police checkpoints but only once they wanted to check papers, but didn't look at my drivers license. I think it doesn't matter here.

There is no officially recognized "digital IDP". The Vienna Convention on Road Traffic, which Egypt is a signatory to, specifies the IDP as being a paper booklet, issued by an organization specifically authorized by the country that issued the driving license.
There are plenty of websites that are willing to take your money to give you something that they call an "IDP". It is not useful for you to do this. If you want an actual IDP, check with the government service which issued your driving license to find out what organization is authorized to issue IDPs.
And, needless to say, if you want to find out what documentation a particular rental company requires, you should ask them. There is no set of documentation which all rental car companies are legally required to accept as sufficient.

In other words I might as well issue my self a "digital IDP" and save myself 25 EUR?

Basically. Even if one wanted a fake IDP, a "digital IDP" would not be a convincing one.

So I guess my real question is, if car rental places will give me a car? This such high grade nonsense, I doubt cops are even checking it. I

@Sneftel However, sometimes a document that looks official can work for you, even if it is not official, as it gives you something to wave under the noses of people who are expecting you only to have "something"

@user1721135 Again, this is a question for the rental car company.

I am looking for people to share their experiences. I can't call anyone while in Egypt. I have 3 different sim cards, even internet is barely working.

@user1721135 It seems like “not being able to ask questions of the people who are qualified to answer them, or in fact to contact anybody” is rather more pressing an issue to address. And, of course, those rental car companies have websites, with contact forms.

Other people's experiences, while interesting, may not be helpful when you're stuck in front of the rental company clerk demanding an IDP. What good is it for you to know that another clerk at some other location at a different point of time didn't demand it from a different person whom you don't even personally know?

I plan on simply going to the office and booking directly. Guess Ill just give it a try. I want to know if in Egypt its mostly required or rather not. Many countries don't really care about this, others take it very seriously, like Japan.

The problem may be with insurance, after the fact, when you need it and they decline it because you weren't legally allowed to drive. You can complain that they gave you the car without checking all you want, but if the contract and the law require you to have an IDP and you didn't - you may have problems. Just FYI.

@littleadv thats a good point, in a heavy incident it could play a role. For a couple of scratches probably not. I got the insurance and am very glad, the speed bumps here are designed in a way that they scrape the bottom of the car or something, I haven't found a way to prevent it completely.
